# In .net 6.0, RabbitMQ.Client v6.4.0 queue returns nothing

Tags: c#, web-applications, rabbitmq, .net-6.0

I made a producer in another program which pushes data into the RabbitMQ queue. It pushes json-like format which is then converted into a serialized object.
`

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName= "localhost" };
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.QueueDeclare(
    queue: "consumption",
    durable: false,
    exclusive: false,
    autoDelete: false,
    arguments: null);

Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid deviceId = new("43215a86-47af-4ccb-3832-08dabf2b75a9");
DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

var message = new
{
    id = id,
    deviceId = deviceId,
    timestamp = timestamp,
    energy_consumption = 1
};

var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

channel.BasicPublish("", "consumption", null, body);
```

`

When I try to use my .net 6.0 web api as a consumer to read the contents of the queue - it returns nothing and I cannot understand why.

`

```
[HttpPost]
        public void RabbitMQConsumer(Timestamp timestampRequest)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            channel.QueueDeclare(
                queue: "consumption",
                durable: false,
                exclusive: false,
                autoDelete: false,
                arguments: null
                );

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            byte[] body;
            string message = null;
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            };
//using debugger
//body -> null
//message - > null
            if (message != null)
            {
                UpdateTimestamps(message);
            }

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "consumption", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer); 
        }
```

`
UpdateTimestamps() is not finished yet, but it is there as an empty method. I tried using the debugger to see what the 'body' and 'message' look like after consumer.Received, but they are still null. How can this problem be fixed?

I am expecting body or message to successfully retrieve all the data that is sent from the producer in any form because even if it isn't in a json format, I can parse the message afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Consuming from queues in RabbitMQ is asynchronous. In your case, the `RabbitMQConsumer` method exits before the `Received` callback has a chance to do anything.

You will have to set up a long-running consumer in your .NET 6 Web API application, most likely during application startup. Then, when messages arrive, store them to be read when `RabbitMQConsumer` is called.

This is an interesting enough scenario that if you would like to share your **complete** code via a git hosting service, I could then review and give feedback. I must be able to clone, compile, and run your project. I am one of the primary maintainers of the RabbitMQ .NET client.

Comment: https://github.com/bogdanciuciuc/stack-rabbitMQ.git

Comment: How would setting up a long-running consumer be done though? I don't really know how that would actually be implemented.

Comment: See my fork: https://github.com/lukebakken/stackoverflow-queue-returns-nothing-74634854. If you'd like to discuss the code, open an issue here - https://github.com/lukebakken/stackoverflow-queue-returns-nothing-74634854/issues. NOTE: my code is UNTESTED but it should work. It basically saves the last message consumed. If you need to consume more than one at a time, use an intermediate queue. I don't know your use-case.

Comment: After a bit of research and trial and error, I understood what Luke was trying to say. The point was that the first time the program was accessing the queue, all the items were dropped and next times it was going to read the data from there (I couldn't understand it at that time). I followed this method and put the reading in a for loop because it was the simplest, good enough way and I was pressured by deadline. I have seen the other method, but I haven't really had time to test. Thanks for the help!